# Strange python's hashlib.md5 behavior, different hash each time

Tags: python, hash

I've faced some really strange behavior trying to calculate md5 hash of string. Returned hash is always wrong (and different) if I pass string that was result of concatenation. Only way to get real hash I've found is to pass string that wasn't modified in any way after creation.

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.md5() 
>>> a1 = "stack"
>>> a2 = "overflow"
>>> a3 = a1 + a2
>>> a4 = str(a1 + a2)
>>> m.update("stackoverflow")
>>> m.hexdigest()
'73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc' //actuall hash
>>> m.update(a1 + a2)
>>> m.hexdigest()
'458b7358b9e0c3f561957b96e543c5a8'
>>> m.update(a3)
>>> m.hexdigest()
'65b0e62d4ff2d91e111ecc8f27f0e8f5'
>>> m.update(a4)
>>> m.hexdigest()
'60c3ae3dd9a2095340b2e024194bad3c'
>>> m.update(a1 + a2)
>>> m.hexdigest()
'acd4e14145d34dcb10af785badf8e73e'
>>> m.update(a1 + a2)
>>> m.hexdigest()
'03c06ca09faa26166f1096db02272b11'
>>> a1 + a2 == a1 + a2
True
>>> a1 + a2 == a3
True
>>> a3 == a4
True
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are missing is that `hash.update()` **doesn't replace the hashed data**. You are continually updating the hash object, so you are getting the hash of the *concatenated strings*. From the [`hashlib.hash.update()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update):

> Update the hash object with the string *arg*. **Repeated calls are equivalent to a single call with the concatenation of all the arguments: `m.update(a)`; `m.update(b)` is equivalent to `m.update(a+b)`.**

Bold emphasis mine.

So you are not getting the hash of a single `'stackoverflow'` string, you are getting the hash first of `'stackoverflow'`, then of `'stackoverflowstackoverflow'`, then `'stackoverflowstackoverflowstackoverflow'` etc., each time *appending* another `'stackoverflow'` creating a longer and longer string. None of those longer strings are equal to the original short string so their hashes are not likely to be equal either.

Create a *new* object for new strings, instead:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update('stack' + 'overflow')
>>> m.hexdigest()
'73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc'
>>> m = hashlib.md5()   # **new** hash object
>>> m.update('stackoverflow')
>>> m.hexdigest()
'73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc'
>>> m = hashlib.md5()     # new object again
>>> m.update('stack')     # add the string in pieces, part 1
>>> m.update('overflow')  # and part 2
>>> m.hexdigest()
'73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc'
```

You can readily produce your 'wrong' hashes by sending in concatenated data:

```
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update('stackoverflowstackoverflow')
>>> m.hexdigest()
'458b7358b9e0c3f561957b96e543c5a8'
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update('stackoverflowstackoverflowstackoverflow')
>>> m.hexdigest()
'65b0e62d4ff2d91e111ecc8f27f0e8f5'
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update('stackoverflow' * 4)
>>> m.hexdigest()
'60c3ae3dd9a2095340b2e024194bad3c'
```

Note that you can also pass in the first string into the `md5()` function:

```
>>> hashlib.md5('stackoverflow').hexdigest()
'73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc'
```

You normally use the `hash.update()` method only if you are processing data in chunks (like reading a file line by line or reading blocks of data from a socket), and don't want to have to hold all of that data in memory at once.

Comment: Link to the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That was completely my fault on not reading documentation superficially and not farther than creating object and passing data with update(), eh.