# Python Hashlib Returning Different Values

Tags: python, md5, sha256, hashlib

~~SOLUTION AT END~~

I need to check the integrity of two files sent over FTP. I have everything set up except SHA256 hashes. Let me explain it from code.

```
BLOCK_SIZE = 65536
hasher = hashlib.sha256()
with open('/home/pi/' + fname, "rb") as targ:
    buf = targ.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
    while len(buf) > 0:
        hasher.update(buf)
        buf = targ.read(BLOCK_SIZE)

checkfile = open("osha256.txt", "w+")
checkfile.write(hasher.hexdigest())
```

and

```
hasher = hashlib.sha256()
with open("/home/pi/" + xr, "rb") as targ:
    buf = targ.read(BUF_SIZE)
    while len(buf) > 0:
        hasher.update(buf)
        buf = targ.read()

hashfile = open("/home/pi/vercheck/sha256.txt", "w+")
hashfile.write(str("{0}".format(hasher.hexdigest())))
```

First one returns hash value(?) of: c8a31cb076b21999bd2cdcfa5f446a7a6644de88037087112fa18bd90cc13984

Second one returns hash value of:
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

File names and directories are same.

Also

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()
with open('/home/pi/cd.jpg', "rb") as targ1:
    buf = targ1.read(bufsize)
    while len(buf) > 0:
        md5.update(buf)
        buf = targ1.read(bufsize)
    checkfile = open("1md5.txt", "w+")
    checkfile.write(md5.hexdigest())
## RETURNS e1d147695131c7682372e26a36c4f6fa

with open('/home/pi/cd.jpg', "rb") as targ1:
    buf = targ1.read(bufsize)
    while len(buf) > 0:
         md5.update(buf)
         buf = targ1.read(bufsize)
    checkfile = open("2md5.txt", "w+")
    checkfile.write(md5.hexdigest()
##RETURNS 3966cdd94eaf06d30c5e6f25eecb6015
```

**EDIT**

You can solve this by adding (in my case) another 
`md5 = hahslib.md5()` top of

```
with open('/home/pi/cd.jpg', "rb") as targ1:
    buf = targ1.read(bufsize)
    while len(buf) > 0:
         md5.update(buf)
         buf = targ1.read(bufsize)
    checkfile = open("2md5.txt", "w+")
    checkfile.write(md5.hexdigest()
```

Comment: Do you create a new hash object in between the chunks of code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697311/strange-pythons-hashlib-md5-behavior-different-hash-each-time

Comment: And now you know why you should only ask one question per question.