# Different Result When Calculating MD5 of Certain Part of a File from Two Identical Files using Python Hashlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, hashlib, md5sum

**Goals :** Make a function to calculate certain part of a file where we skips certain bytes.

[image: Only certain parts of file to be calculated]

**Problem :** Testing on two identical files makes different results.

[image: Full file calculation already correct. While the parts one are wrong for identical files]

**Code :**

```
def checksum_contentonly(filename,sum_part, hash_factory=hashlib.md5, chunk_num_blocks=128):
    h = hash_factory()
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        for i in range(0,sum_part):
            if i==0:
                f.seek(240,0)
            else:
                f.seek(1240,1)
            chunk=f.read(1000)
            h.update(chunk)
    f.close()
    return h
```

Comment: how do you run it ? Maybe you test part on different file or it was changed between test.

Comment: if you use `with open(...)` then you don't have to use `close()` becaus `with` will close it automatically.

Comment: you can alwys use `print()` to see values in variables when you run function - maybe they are different when you run it second time so it gives different result.

Comment: maybe this problem is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697311/strange-pythons-hashlib-md5-behavior-different-hash-each-time

Comment: @furas it's a same file, I just copy-pasted it. thanks for the tips, though its still showing the same value (of course it's a duplicate) but the MD5 still different. I wonder if we have to use specific size when using MD5.

Comment: I would get both partial data and save in two files to compare them. Maybe it will show that they use different parts of file. Using text file it would be easier to recognize which part of file they used. You could also display values in variable which are used in `checksum_contentonly` - maybe they are not identical.